# ModuleNotFoundError in VS code with Jupyter note book but not .py files

Tags: python, pandas, visual-studio-code, pip, jupyter-notebook

I am using visual studio code on windows, and I am trying to run a python code on jupyter-notebook. I have all packages installed and they work fine when it is a normal python file. But I need it to run as a notebook. Once I run the block, I immediately get the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_5668\1439934476.py in <module>
      1 import csv
----> 2 from pandas import read_csv
      3 from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
      4 import numpy as np
      5 import os

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
```

I made sure that requirements are already satsified for this module, and I already tried running this line in python file with no issues. Therefore, how can I solve this issue? How can I let Jupyter notebook compiler to see where these packages actually are?

Comment: Do you have more than one version of Python installed?

Comment: Yup, the issue was fixed but I don't know how. (Alone).

Answer (score 1):

First you need to install *pandas* by running the command in your console:

```
pip install pandas
```

If you don't have pip installed on your computer then install it, otherwise you won't be able to download *pandas* or other modules

PS: check that when you downloaded python you chose the *add to PATH* option

Hoping I could help

Comment: I did all this but didn't solve the issue. Suddenly after switching between different python versions, the issue was solved alone. Thanks anyway but I cannot claim this would help.

Comment: @TravelingSalesman . Ultimately sorting out getting the kernel backing your Jupyter notebook using the same environment as your script may be important if you are using Jupyter a lot. How to do it depends on how you are using things and the easiest of novices is probably to use the Anaconda distribution and see about environments and Jupyter for that software manager. If you rarely use Jupyter and you just want to get past a hurdle such as this, run `%pip install pandas` in a cell in your notebook. That magic command insures it installs the package in the environment backing the notebook. ...

Comment: <continuing> And sometimes that is just easier. ( Especially when it's something mature & fairly stable like Pandas.) Sometimes you just want to get past the hurdle & get your code running. There's a a related `%conda install` magic command that works inside cells in a notebook now, too. See [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez) for more about these magic commands that you can run in cells in your Jupyter notebooks. **You want to restart the kernel after such installations.** You can still use `Run all` after.

Answer (score 1):

The installation of pip is related to the python path specified in the environment variable. You need to select the correct interpreter in vscode.

Python is an interpreted language, and in order to run Python code and get Python IntelliSense, you must tell VS Code which interpreter to use.

From within VS Code, select a Python 3 interpreter by opening the Command Palette (**Ctrl+Shift+P**), start typing the `Python: Select Interpreter` command to search, then select the command. You can also use the Select Python Environment option on the Status Bar if available (it may already show a selected interpreter, too):
[image]

Read [docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial#_select-a-python-interpreter) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a problem running jupyter notebook file make sure

1. You have installed jupyter notebook from anaconda from this [site](https://www.anaconda.com/)
2. Once you installed that, open anaconda navigator and click `environment` tab
3. Install `python` and `pandas`

Jupyter Notebook works like environment different from VSCode

You can also run Jupyter Notebook file on VSCode by installing `Jupyter` extension in VSCode

My guess is you don't installed it yet in anaconda navigator, that's what makes it error

Answer (score 0):

The VSCode python may not be where you think it is.  In a Jupyter cell issue the magic command

```
%pip install pandas
```

and see if that gives you a clue to your environment.